# When Object is loaded into memory?

Tags: actionscript-3, textures, starling-framework

How can I check when this operation:

```
Page2 = Texture.fromBitmap(new Page2Class(), true, true, FactorScaler);
```

is complete (process finished, Page2 ready to use on stage) and I'm ready for loading next Page3 object and so on?

Now I use timer with static time being set. But it's not optimal, I wait too much sometimes and too short other time. I need to know exact time.

This should run in Starling Framework on Android and iOS.

Ps.: If I don't wait the app will crash due to too heavy pipeline.

Comment: good question , have you tried asking at starling forum?

Comment: So far I was answered to add the new Image of Texture to the stage and wait for Event.ADDED_TO_STATE, remove from stage and wait for Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE and then proceed.

Comment: ok about `ADDED` but why also wait for `REMOVED` ?

Comment: You dont want XXX elements on the stage so you need to remove them. And it's better to wait for confirmation than to proceed new tasks while still occupying cpu/gpu with removing objects (at I think so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by Jeff on Starling forum:
http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/when-texture-object-is-loaded

Information about Texture being fully loaded is dispatched from Texture.fromAtfData method's 4th parameter (function). So to use it your asset needs to be of ATF format.